# Kfserving Example Issue -- failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubeflow

I installed KFserving together with Kubeflow on my k8s cluster, but when I tried to run the Sklearn example provided here: https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/:

[image]

Then I checked the resources under the namespace -- it was unsuccessful, and the STATUS i noticed is `Revision Missing`

```
NAME                                                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                             AGE
service/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg           ClusterIP   172.21.100.57   <none>        80/TCP                              4m32s
service/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-private   ClusterIP   172.21.69.241   <none>        80/TCP,9090/TCP,9091/TCP,8022/TCP   4m32s

NAME                                                              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment   0/1     0            0           4m32s

NAME                                                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   1         0         0       4m32s

NAME                                                               LATESTCREATED                          LATESTREADY   READY     REASON
configuration.serving.knative.dev/sklearn-iris-predictor-default   sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg                 Unknown

NAME                                                                CONFIG NAME                      K8S SERVICE NAME                       GENERATION   READY     REASON
revision.serving.knative.dev/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg   sklearn-iris-predictor-default   sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg   1            Unknown   Deploying

NAME                                                       URL                                                                READY     REASON
route.serving.knative.dev/sklearn-iris-predictor-default   http://sklearn-iris-predictor-default.kfserving-test.example.com   Unknown   RevisionMissing

NAME                                                         URL                                                                LATESTCREATED                          LATESTREADY   READY     REASON
service.serving.knative.dev/sklearn-iris-predictor-default   http://sklearn-iris-predictor-default.kfserving-test.example.com   sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg                 Unknown   RevisionMissing
```

Also in the event: `kubectl get event -n kfserving-test` I saw `error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c4598k2x" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory`

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              OBJECT                                                                  MESSAGE
6m23s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c4598k2x" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
6m23s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45mdgks" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
6m23s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45xvlkq" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
6m23s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45rq2m4" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
6m22s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45845f8" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
6m22s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45n4wcc" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
6m22s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c452jvl8" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
6m22s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45xj4xj" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
6m21s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45grhdr" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
52s         Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45   (combined from similar events): Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c4544wbm" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory
6m23s       Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment              Scaled up replica set sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c45 to 1
6m37s       Warning   InternalError       serverlessservice/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg                  failed to get private K8s Service endpoints: endpoints "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-private" not found
6m37s       Warning   InternalError       revision/sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg                           failed to update deployment "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment": Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.apps "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
6m38s       Normal    Created             service/sklearn-iris-predictor-default                                  Created Configuration "sklearn-iris-predictor-default"
6m38s       Normal    Created             configuration/sklearn-iris-predictor-default                            Created Revision "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg"
6m38s       Normal    Created             service/sklearn-iris-predictor-default                                  Created Route "sklearn-iris-predictor-default"
6m38s       Normal    FinalizerUpdate     route/sklearn-iris-predictor-default                                    Updated "sklearn-iris-predictor-default" finalizers
5m43s       Normal    Updated             inferenceservice/sklearn-iris                                           Updated InferenceService "sklearn-iris"
5m44s       Warning   InternalError       inferenceservice/sklearn-iris                                           Operation cannot be fulfilled on services.serving.knative.dev "sklearn-iris-predictor-default": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

I've also checked the `Revision Missing` section in the following guide still but no idea, I doubt it's related to `Error creating: pods "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-7tjcg-deployment-6495b57c4598k2x" is forbidden: failed quota: kf-resource-quota: must specify memory`
https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/blob/master/docs/KFSERVING_DEBUG_GUIDE.md

Istio Version: 1.6.13

Knative Version:

KFServing Version:

Kubeflow version:1.2.0

Kubernetes version: (use kubectl version): client:1.19.4, server:1.17

OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release): macOS Catalina

Comment: Hello. I've used the guide that you linked and couldn't replicate the issue you're having. Could you tell more about your cluster setup? Is your Kubernetes cluster on your Mac? Is it a `minikube` or `Docker Desktop`?

Comment: Hello Dawid, my cluster is an Azure Kubernetes cluster and Kfserving was installed together with Kubeflow

Comment: Do you have any `LimitRange` or `ResourceQuota` objects created in your cluster? It looks like they can be blocking the `Pod` creation. Please take a look on following links: [ResourceQuota docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-memory-cpu-namespace/#:~:text=Every%20Container%20must%20have%20a,must%20not%20exceed%201%20cpu.), [LimitRange docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look!

Comment: have you managed to solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be several issues: 1. Istio was not correctly installed, need to config the IngressGateWay; 2. Google Cloud Storage was not available in my environment so we have to use either K8s native storage / local file system.

Comment: as you found solution to your issue please post your comment as an answer with an explanation how you've managed to solve it. This will certainly help community members if they are stumble upon same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar issue in the past when working on GCP, first make sure you have a proper amount of Resource Quota available for your cluster, you may need to request an increase depending on your provider. Second, make sure that your Istio service mesh has an `IngressGateway` that is properly configured so that the `sklearn-iris-predictor` can be reached.